# Accessing an instance object within an instance object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instance, inventory

So pretty new to C# and trying to create a simple inventory from a .tsv file

I have a script (text parser) which reads the file, creates an instance of an object called 'TableData' and transfers all data to this instance.

The relevant part of the text parser looks like this:

```
public class TextParser : MonoBehaviour {
...
...

            line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] tableKey = line.Split('\t');

            line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] typeKey = line.Split('\t');

            line = reader.ReadLine();
            string[] entries = line.Split('\t');

            TableData tableData = new TableData(tableKey,typeKey,entries);
...
...
```

*later in the script i have a loop that adds each additional line to a list IN that instance

The TableData script has just 3 fields: 2 string arrays and 1 list of string arrays:

```
public class TableData : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string[] tableKey;
    public string[] tableType;
    public List<string[]> excelData = new List<string[]>();


    public TableData(string[] _tableKey, string[] _tableType, string[] entries)
    {
        tableKey = _tableKey;
        tableType = _tableType;

        excelData.Add (entries);
    }
}
```

So the question is, if i instance an object of the 'TextParser' class (on runtime), and in turn it instances an object of the 'TableData' class- how can i access the data in the 'tableData' instance?

Comment: `tableData.excelData` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
    public class TableData : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public string[] tableKey;
        public string[] tableType;
        public DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        public TableData()
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("Key", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Type", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Entry", typeof(string));
        }


        public TableData(string[] _tableKey, string[] _tableType, string[] entries)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < _tableKey.Length; i++)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { _tableKey[i], _tableType[i], entries[i] });
            }

        }
    }
​
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it public, and in the `class` scope

```
public class TextParser : MonoBehaviour {
    //...
    public TableData tableData;
    //...
}
```

then you just do

```
TextParser tp;
TableData tableData = tp.tableData;
// Do something
```